# Continued fractions, Chebyshev and non-homogenous approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

In Khinchin's book, "Continued Fractions," he considers the question, given an irrational, $\alpha$, and a real number, $\beta$, how to find integral $x$ and $y$ such that
$$\alpha x - y \approx \beta$$
to a given level of accuracy.

He then says that Chebyshev "obtained the first basic results connected with it, and has been the subject of continued intensive study, especially by the Soviet arithmetic school." Khinchin goes on to prove a few interesting theorems concerning this question, but then moves on to other topics.

Where can I find more about work that has been done on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our question is a very special case of the general problem of restricted simultaneous Diophantine approximation. Thus, I believe that the best place to start is to consult the paper of Schmidt: *Two questions in Diophantine approximation*, Monatsh. Math. 82, 237-245. Moreover, you also should consult the paper of P. Thurnheer: *On Dirichlet's theorem concerning diophantine approximation*, Acta Arithmetica 54 (1990), 241--250 and reference therein.

Comment: Thank you. One of these refers to the Davenport-Schmidt theorem; see H Davenport & Wolfgang Schmidt, "Approximation to real numbers by quadratic irrationals," Acta Arithmetica 13 (1967), 169-176. That's also useful.